# Enumeration in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

i am a C# programmer and i am looking in to ruby on rails. but i am having some trouble probably with the mind set or something.

I have an object Vote, that object can be Pro, Neutral or con.

I would normaly make the vote object have a field some thing like this

```
private VoteEnum voteEnum = VoteEnum.Neutral
```

how on earth can i acomplish this in ruby.

i have found some examples like:

```
def MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  ACTIVE_STATUS = "active"
  INACTIVE_STATUS = "inactive"
  PENDING_STATUS = "pending"
end
```

Then, when using the model from another class, I reference the constants

```
@model.status = MyClass::ACTIVE_STATUS
@model.save
```

This seems correct to me but my main question is how do i tell the model that status is the type of enum or constain..

I hope you understand my question, and hope you can help me get my mind wrapped around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby isn't strictly-typed like C#. But you can use validations to check what's in the status:

```
def MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    ACTIVE_STATUS = "active"
    INACTIVE_STATUS = "inactive"
    PENDING_STATUS = "pending"
    NUMERICAL_STATUS = 500 # this is weird but okay

    ALL_STATUSES = [ACTIVE_STATUS, INACTIVE_STATUS, PENDING_STATUS, NUMERICAL_STATUS]

    validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => ALL_STATUSES

end
```

Comment: So what type is status then? string? i have to save the value to the database so.

Comment: Yes, it will only be successfully saved in a string column... but I'll amend the example a bit to show another possibility.

Comment: This helps allot, sorry for being a giant n00b but can't help it.
do you also know how to use this in the views? like a select or something?

Comment: There are lots of helpers in views which can do, e.g. <select>:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002249

Comment: You can write a getter method that returns an array of possible statuses.

Comment: yeah i am aware of the helpers, but i mend in C# i could get a list or array of all the values of the enum and pass that to the view engine so i could use a select helper to build the option's. buy the way thanx allot for helping me so much!

Comment: I see i have to write my own function for that, in C# i used reflection but this could work to thanks for all the help i think i can get started now!

Comment: Since validates_inclusion_of already has that array, I made it constant so you can use it in views too.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if it is just an enum as used in C++ or C#, i would translate that as follows:

```
class VoteStatus
  ACTIVE_STATUS=0
  INACTIVE_STATUS=1
  PENDING_STATUS=2
end
```

so you store an integer in your database, and the meaning is clear in your code.

However, i would suggest using a simple domain table for this. That way you define and can maintain the possible statuses inside your database, you define an id, name and description and suddenly your statuses are self-documented and names and descriptions can be shown to the user as well (hoping you don't need translations :).